# Excel unable to skip blanks in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have some calculations on column C with values from 0 to 100, and I want to highlight any cell that contains a value of less than 95.  I added conditional formatting where if cell value < 95, the cell is shown in red, using the formula =$C:$C.  Of course this means that all the empty cells are getting marked as red but I want these to remain unformatted.

I have tried editing the formula to something like =AND($C<>"",$C:$C) but on clicking apply the formula is automatically switched to =($C:$C).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the column you want to apply the conditional formatting on (in your case **C**). Set the formula as **`=And($C1<95, $C1>0)`**

Comment: It doesn't work for me.  On apply, the formula is revert to =$C:$C.  However your approach would apply for cell C1 only yes?  I need the formula to apply to the whole column

Comment: Select the column before you apply conditional formatting. And the formula wont apply just to C1, it will be applied to the column.. if you select the column before applying conditional formatting

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Zac, I was doing something stupid.  Your formula worked fine! thanks :)

Comment: No worries, glad it helped